# Using redis to store a structured event log

Tags: ruby, data-structures, redis

I'm a bit new to Redis, so please forgive if this is basic.

I'm working on an app that sends automatic replies to users for certain events. I would like to use Redis to store who has received what event.

Essentially, in ruby, the data structure could look like this where you have a map of users to events and the dates that each event was sent.

```
{
  "mary@example.com" => {
    "sent_comment_reply" => ["12/12/2014", "3/6/2015"],
    "added_post_reply" => ["1/4/2006", "7/1/2016"]
  }
}
```

What is the best way to represent this in a Redis data structure so you can ask, did Mary get a sent_comment_reply? and if so, when was the latest?

In short, the question is, how(if possible) can you have a Hash structure that holds an array in Redis.

The rationale as opposed to using a set or list with a compound key is that hashes have O(1) lookup time, whereas lookups on lists(lrange) and sets(smembers) will be O(s+n) and sets O(n), respectively.

Comment: Try the documentation, or at least this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Redis_Tips

Comment: I"ve done that, but they don't really address best practices for complex data structures

Answer (score 0):

One way of structuring it in Redis, depending on the idea that you know the events of the user and you want the latest to be fresh in memory :

1. A sorted set per user. the content of the sorted set will be event codes; `sent_comment_reply`, `added_post_reply` with the score of the latest event as the highest. you can use `ZRANK` to get the answer for the question :

   Did Mary get a sent_comment_reply?
2. A hash also for the user, this time you will have the field as the event `sent_comment_reply` and the value is the content of it which should be updated with the latest value including the body, date, etc. this will answer the question:

   and if so, when was the latest?

Note: [Sorted sets are really fast](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets) , and in this example we are depending on the events as the data.

> With sorted sets you can add, remove, or update elements in a very
>   fast way (in a time proportional to the logarithm of the number of
>   elements). Since elements are taken in order and not ordered
>   afterwards, you can also get ranges by score or by rank (position) in
>   a very fast way. Accessing the middle of a sorted set is also very
>   fast, so you can use Sorted Sets as a smart list of non repeating
>   elements where you can quickly access everything you need: elements in
>   order, fast existence test, fast access to elements in the middle!

Comment: interesting approach, so you use two different data structures that are conceptually linked by the user. However, this approach does not seem to store the history of times that the event occurred.

Comment: I wasn't able to conclude this from your question, but it depends on how fast and how much you want to keep into Redis. either you can add it as an attribute in the data saved in your hash already per event, or you will need a new structure for this which is another hash like the previous and using `HINCRBY`

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach to use a hash to map an array is as follows:

```
add_element(key , value):

 len := redis.hlen(key)
 redis.hset(key , len , value)
```

this will map `array[i]` element to `i` field in a hash key.

this will work for some cases, but I would probably go with the answer  suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886801/2868839